# Seperate button to reset dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, button, drop-down-menu

I have this dropdown.

The idea would be when you click on the dropdown and click on any Item, I would like to have a separate button that I can place anywhere on my page that would reset the dropdown to "1st".

Any suggestion?

```js
<!-- .ajaxd-posts --><script type="text/javascript">(function($) {$("#ajaxd-select-37006").change(function(){$.post("http://www.willgetitnow.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",{"action":"ajax_dropdown","post_id":$(this).val()},function(response){if(response!=0){$("#ajaxd-posts-37006").html(response)};});}).trigger("change");})(jQuery);</script></h4>
</div>
```

```html
<div id="services_rightarea">
<h4 style="text-align: center;"><select class="ajaxd-select" name="ajax_post" id="ajaxd-select-37006"><option value="33251" data-permalink="http://www.blablabla.com/choose-a-state/" selected="selected">Choose a State</option><option value="8984" data-permalink="http://blablabla.com/california-restaurants/">California</option></select><div class="ajaxd-posts" id="ajaxd-posts-37006"><div class="ajaxd-post" id="ajaxd-post-33251"></div></div>
</div>




<h4 style="text-align: center;"><button type="button" >reset</button>
<p>reset to "Choose your state"<p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `onclick` event on button and set `selected index` of the dropdown to 0

```html
<select class="ajaxd-select" name="ajax_post" id="ajaxd-select-37006"><option value="33251" data-permalink="http://www.blablabla.com/blablabla" selected="selected">first</option><option value="8984" data-permalink="http://">2nd</option><option value="8984" data-permalink="http://">3rd</option><option value="8984" data-permalink="http://">4th</option><option value="8984" data-permalink="http://">5th</option><option value="8984" data-permalink="http://">6th</option></select>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()" >reset</button> reset to "1st"
<script>
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("ajaxd-select-37006").selectedIndex =0;
    //remove all options except first
    document.getElementById("ajaxd-select-37006").options.length = 1;
}
</script>
```

I had a look at your source code, please see inline comments below :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
        $("#ajaxd-select-37006").change(function() {

            // this function gets called everytime you change dropdwon selection
            $.post("http://www.willgetitnow.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", {
                "action": "ajax_dropdown",
                "post_id": $(this).val()
            }, function(response) {
                if (response != 0) {
                    $("#ajaxd-posts-37006").html(response) // here you are assiging values to dropdown
                };
            });
        }).trigger("change");
    })(jQuery);
</script>
```

So whatever i am trying to do on button click isn't of much importance when it comes to removing all elements, the code i shared selects first item (and removes all other entries too !) but as soon as you go and change selected item in dropdown, items are repopulated via ajax request.

Comment: Thank you Ankit, your function worked. I tested it on my website. But I do have a small problem. It is not removing the dropdown content. So when I click on "reset"  it actually goes back to first but the content from 2nd is still there. Almost as though it just changed the name of the dropdown but didnt actually reset. OR maybe I didnt give you enough information. Would this help ?   test here-   www.willgetitnow.com

Comment: i have edited my answer in response to your comment, have a look. Also please accept my answer if this helps you.

Comment: The first answer you had worked better. And everything works perfect, it just doesn't act like it is being clicked. But if I click on the actually dropdown then it works. So somehow the button is not resetting the content.

Comment: I improved my question above

Answer (score 0):

Ok So I edited my answer and got this hope this helps!

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    (function($) {
      $("#ajaxd-select-37006").change(function() {
        $.post("http://www.willgetitnow.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", {
          "action": "ajax_dropdown",
          "post_id": $(this).val()
        }, function(response) {
          if (response != 0) {
            $("#ajaxd-posts-37006").html(response)
          };
        });
      }).trigger("change");
    })(jQuery);
  </script>

</head>

<body>
  <div id="services_rightarea">
    <h4 style="text-align: center;"><select class="ajaxd-select" name="ajax_post" id="ajaxd-select-37006"><option value="33251" data-permalink="http://www.blablabla.com/choose-a-state/" selected="selected">Choose a State</option><option value="8984" data-permalink="http://blablabla.com/california-restaurants/">California</option></select>
      <div
        class="ajaxd-posts" id="ajaxd-posts-37006">
        <div class="ajaxd-post" id="ajaxd-post-33251"></div>
  </div>
  </div>




  <h4 style="text-align: center;">
    <input type="button" id="R" value="Reset form" />
    <p>reset to "Choose your state"
      <p>
        <script>
   

          $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#R").click(function() {
              $('#ajaxd-select-37006').get(0).selectedIndex = 0;
            });
          });
        </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: That would be good! Do you know how I could make that working using this? <select class="ajaxd-select" name="ajax_post" id="ajaxd-select-37006"><option value="33251" data-permalink="http://www.blablabla.com/choose-a-state/" selected="selected">Choose a State</option><option value="8984" data-permalink="http://www.blablabla/california/">California</option></select>